# Integrating Woocommerce and magento?

Tags: woocommerce

I built my website on Magento, and would like to keep it on Magento.

However, I recently did a Wordpress install on my site as well, which was sort of a pain to get working. The reason why I installed Worpress is to utilize a custom product configurator that was available for Woocommerce, I tried building the same thing for Magento but it was just not possible.

So now my problem is that I have two different checkouts on my website.. one for the Woocommerce products (right now only 4 products) and hundreds of products on Magento. If the customer adds the Woocommerce product to their cart then goes back to Magento, it will cause confusion as they are two different carts.

Is there any way to have the Woocommerce products merge with the Magento cart?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: For just 4 products it's not going to be the optimal use of resources to code a solution. Just migrate the 4 products manually.